# Jquery click event if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm adding trivia as a main component to my webpage. I'm trying to the class of "correct" when it's right, and "wrong" when it's wrong. I have no idea what I'm doing. lol. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    <ul>
        <li id="a">A) Lucy</li>
        <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
        <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
        <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
    </ul>
```

JQuery

I tried to make the correct one a variable in Jquery

```
 var right = $( "ul li#a" ).on(click, function() {});

 if (click === right){
     $("ul li#a").addClass("correct");
 } else {
     $("li").addClass("wrong");
 }
```

Comment: Your JavaScript is wrong in several ways: `li#a` isn't valid, `.on(click` should be `.on('click'`, you're passing an empty function to a click handler, your `right` variable is the return value of `.on()`... I've given you an answer with code that does what you're trying to do, but I strongly suggest you spend some time with a jQuery tutorial before you post more questions.

Comment: I agree 100%. I thought I was ready until I started my own projects. I'm starting a tutorial today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your end goal, you want to do something to indicate that an answer is the "right" answer or not, then you want to assign class `.correct` or `.wrong` if they get the "right" answer or not.

I would assign `data-right="right"` to the "right" answer. Then when someone clicks on an `li`, look for that attribute and assign `.correct` if they chose the "right" answer, and assign `.wrong` if not.

```js
$('li').on('click',function() {
  var right = $(this).data('right');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('correct wrong');
  if (right == "right") {
    $(this).addClass('correct');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('wrong');
  }
})
```

```css
.correct {
  color: green;
}
.correct:after {
  content: '\2713';
}
.wrong {
  color: red;
}
.wrong:after {
  content: '\2613';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="a" data-right="right">A) Lucy</li>
  <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
  <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
  <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @willed89 no sweat!

Answer (score 1):

This solution relies on giving the right answers a class called "correctAnswer", then binding a click event handler that sets the class of the clicked `li` based on whether or not it has that class. I think that does what you're looking for:

```
<ul>
    <li id="a" class="correctAnswer">A) Lucy</li>
    <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
    <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
    <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
</ul>

$('li').on('click', function () {
    var classToAdd = $(this).is('.correctAnswer') ? 'correct' : 'wrong';
    $(this).addClass(classToAdd);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete example:

```js
 
    $( document ).ready(function() {

        var correctAnser = 'a'; // you need to set this to what you need the answer to be
     $('ul li').on('click', function () {  
            $('ul li').removeClass('correct').removeClass('wrong'); // remove both classes on list elements
            var classToAdd = $(this).attr('id') == correctAnser ? 'correct' : 'wrong';
            $(this).addClass(classToAdd);
     });
    });
```

```css
.correct {
       background:#2bb539;
       color:#ffffff;
    }
    .wrong {
       background:#c00;
       color:#ffffff;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
        <li id="a">A) Lucy</li>
        <li id="b">B) Bonnie</li>
        <li id="c">C) Sheila</li>
        <li id="d">D) Kai</li>
    </ul>
```